# Removing sublists that contain certain elements of a matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

Consider the matrix:

```
badcombos
      [,1]      [,2] 
[1,] "Red"    "Yellow"
[2,] "Green"  "Yellow"
[3,] "Orange" "Yellow"
[4,] "Blue"   "Green"
[5,] "Blue"   "Purple"
```

Then, the list:

```
allcombos
[[1]]
[1] "Red" "Green" "Orange" "Pink" "Purple"
[[2]]
[1] "Red" "Red" "Brown" "Purple" "Pink"
[[3]]
[1] "Yellow" "Red" "Brown" "Blue" "Purple"
[[4]]
[1] "Yellow" "Green" "Blue" "Purple" "Gold"
....
[[k]] "Red" "Blue" "Orange" "Brown" "Pink
```

How would I "reduce" the list based on conditions that if any of the combinations of colours in the badcombos matrix appear in the list (ie. sublists [[3]] and [[4]] in the above example) then they would be removed from the list.

## Edit - full code:

```
my_list = list()
my_list[[1]] = c("Red","Green","Orange","Pink","Purple")
my_list[[2]] = c("Red","Red","Brown","Purple","Pink")
my_list[[3]] = c("Yellow","Red","Brown","Blue","Purple")
my_list[[4]] = c("Yellow","Green","Blue","Purple","Gold")
my_list[[5]] = c("Red","Blue","Orange","Brown","Pink")

my_matrix = t(matrix(c("Red","Yellow","Green","Yellow","Orange","Yellow","Blue","Green","Blue","Purple"),2,5))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide `badcombos` and `allcombos`. (I.e. edit your post and add the result of `dput(badcombos)` and `dput(allcombos)`.

Comment: I only put those up as a theoretical vector and matrix since the ones I am using are a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Aesler , Luke meant to post the dput as examples to make it easier for us to work on the problem. Otherwise, we have to create objects.

Comment: OK I just quickly edited it with the full code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do that:

```
match_first_col  <- lapply(my_list,match,my_matrix[,1])
match_second_col <- lapply(my_list,match,my_matrix[,2])

#Elements of the list that match both columns:
is.na(mapply(intersect, match_first_col,match_second_col))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#Keep only allcombos with no match in first and second column
my_list[is.na(mapply(intersect, match_first_col,match_second_col))]

[[1]]
[1] "Red"    "Green"  "Orange" "Pink"   "Purple"

[[2]]
[1] "Red"    "Red"    "Brown"  "Purple" "Pink"  

[[3]]
[1] "Red"    "Blue"   "Orange" "Brown"  "Pink"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt using `%in%` to check which values from the 'bad' list are present:

```
sel <- mapply(
  function(a,b) all(rowSums(matrix(b %in% a,ncol=2))<2),
  my_list, list(my_matrix)
)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Then to select the ones you want:

```
my_list[sel]
```